# Multiple group by keeping their orders

Tags: sql, database

Let's consider this example :

```
Clients   Routes   City   Timestamp
1         10        NY       0
1         11        NY       10
1         12        WDC      11    
1         13        NY       20
2         22        LA       15
```

What I want as an output is something like this :

```
Clients   Routes_number    City   min(Timestamp)
1         2                NY       0
1         1                WDC      11    
1         1                NY       20
2         1                LA       15
```

The idea here is that I have to do multiple group by that kept their orders. For example, if we see the cities for Client 1, we can understand that he travelled from NY -> WDC -> NY (in the same day). So the idea is like to do a group by that counts the routes_number and the minimum timestamp but it will stop EACH TIME it finds a new city. If I do a global group by I will get something like this :

```
Clients   Routes_number    City   min(Timestamp)
1         3                NY       0
1         1                WDC      11    
2         1                LA       15
```

With an output like this, we lost the information that we have NY-> WDC and AGAIN NY. We thought that he only did NY -> WDC in one way...

I don't even know if it's possible to do such a request using SQL or if I have to do it in my code (I am newbie in Spark & Scala but Scala is the language that I use).

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem that can be solved with a difference of row numbers:

```
select client, city, count(*), min(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client, city order by timestamp) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by client order by timestamp) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by client, city, (seqnum_2 - seqnum_1);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4b693f2a73d2cbc7d988df9882a73dd7) is a db<>fiddle.

It can be tricky to see how the difference of row numbers works to identify adjacent rows with the same city value.  If you look at the results of the subquery, you'll get a good idea on how it works.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with sql but it "seems" that it gives the same output that I gave as an example. I mean, it does the global group by and we lost the "sub"-group by and their orders...

Comment: @salamanka44 . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  It produces the same result as what you want.